# Where to use ignorecases in python

Tags: python, regex, class

sorry for my bad english writing, I hope you understand what I'm asking for and Im very new to python and I need som help with casesensitive variable. I thought using regularexpression would help, but I might have thought this out wrong.
I want to ask user to type in song title and see if the title already exists.
I have already have a testdata "Hurt", "Johnny Cash".
So if user type "Hurt", it will print out "Title exists", but if user type "hurt" with small letter then it will print out ("Title not exists")

Any tips or help how I can make sure it ignores casesensitive?

Here is the code below:

In Python I made class name **Song**

```
class Song(object):

    #Constructor
    def __init__(self, title, artist):

        #Instance variabler
        self._title = title
        self._artist = artist                                                                         

    def checkTitle(self, title):
       #RegEX
       m = re.search(r"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)[\s]([a-zA-Z0-9]*)",title)
       songTitle = t.group(0)
       print (songTitle) # prints out "hurt" in lower cases from user input(look below the code)

       if sangTittel == self._title:
            print("Title exists")
       else:
           print("Title not exists")                                                              

newSong = Song("Hurt", "Johnny Cash")                                                           
title = input("Write the name of the songtitle: ") #user write hurt in lower cases  

checkTitle(title)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need regex.

Like Reza said you can use `upper()` or `lower()` to fix the case issue and then use `in` to check the title.

`if title.lower() in self._title.lower()`

Comment: thank for your reply. I followed your advice but I got error:
if title.lower() in self._title():
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: `self._title()` should be `self._title.lower()`

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to lowercase everything like this.

```py
def checkTitle(self, title): 
    songTitle = t.lower() 
    print (songTitlle) 
   if songTittel == self._title: 
       print("Title exists") 
    else: 
       print("Title not exists")
```

And do the same in your `__init__` method.

```py
self._title = title.lower()
```

## Note

You have also `capitalize` method, that may be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 're.IGNORECASE' as an argument to re.search:

```
re.search(pattern, string, re.IGNORECASE)
```

and compare directly the user input with the song title:

```
import re

class Song(object):

    #Constructor
    def __init__(self, title, artist):

        #Instance variabler
        self._title = title
        self._artist = artist                                                                         

    def checkTitle(self, title):
       #RegEX       
       if re.search( title, self._title, re.IGNORECASE):
            print("Title exists")
       else:
           print("Title not exists")                                                              

newSong = Song("Hurt", "Johnny Cash")                                                           
title = input("Write the name of the songtitle: ") #user write hurt in lower cases  

newSong.checkTitle(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Python` you can use the methods `str.upper()` or `str.lower()` which return a copy of the string converted to uppercase/lowercase. For your code you can use it like :

```
checkTitle(title.lower())
```

to have the input in lowercase.